# ¿Cómo puedo enviar un texto a un TEdit dentro de un Formulario desde otra aplicación (servicio)?

Tags: delphi, winapi

Quiero enviar un código de barras a un TEdit llamado 'edtCodigo' dentro de una ventana de otra aplicación llamada 'TfrmGuiaMovimiento', estoy usando el siguiente código:

```
var
  h: HWND;
  codigo: string;
  i: Integer;
begin
  h := FindWindow('TfrmGuiaMovimiento',nil);
  if h > 0 then
  begin
    codigo := '7665009887781';
    h := FindWindowEx(h, 0, 'edtCodigo', nil);
    if h > 0 then
    begin
      for i := 1 to codigo.Length do SendMessage(h, WM_CHAR, Ord(codigo[i]), 0);
      PostMessage(h, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, 0);
    end;
  end;
 end;
```

No funciona!!!!
Pero al enviar al Handle directamente funciona.

Comment: Puedes elaborar en qué quieres decir con "al enviar al Handle directamente funciona"?